# How to make DatePickerDialog center of screen in android if dialog choose styles.xml?

Tags: android, android-styles

I choose the dialog of style at coding.

```
new SpinnerDatePickerDialogBuilder()
                .context(RouteAndStop.this)
                .callback(RouteAndStop.this)
                .spinnerTheme(R.style.NumberPickerStyle)
                .showTitle(true)
                .showDaySpinner(true)
                .defaultDate(year, month-1, day)
                .maxDate(2050, 12, 31)
                .minDate(1960, 0, 1)
                .dialogTheme(R.style.SpinnerDialogStyle)
                .build()
                .show();
```

Here is SpinnerDialogStyle.

```
<style name="SpinnerDialogStyle">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/yellow</item>
    <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
</style>
```

What option is center of screen in style.xml? I want to get help about this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
<item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
```